# How long does it take to change xlarge AMI to large AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance, amazon-ami

I created an AWS/EC2 Instance based on Instance ID i-44f81021, which is an EC2 Instance Type
M3 Extra Large (m3.xlarge).

How long should it normally take to reduce the EC2 Instance Type to m3.large?

Thanks,
Ron.

P.S.: the Change instance type from m3.xlarge to m1.large notification is already shown for 30 minutes, and it's still declaring "Working".

Answer (score 1):

usually changing instance type wont take much time ,for me its taking hardly 2-3 seconds .

Comment: Depends upon the storage of EC2 that you're creating an image of.